# Authentication based on http domain with spring-security

Tags: java, spring-security

We are developing an application that will be accessible on different domains (or probably just subdomains) for different clients.

For example client1 will use client1.ourapp.com, client2 will use client2.ourapp.com. Basically app will be the same on both domains, main difference will be branding (i.e. different logo on each site) and of course content will depend on used domain.

Thing is, there should be users, who can login only on one of these sites, other users (like administrators) should be able to log in to both. I have some decent experience with spring security, but I never did something like this and I can't find any documentatation on this. I'm thinking about creating authorities like ROLE_CLIENT1 and ROLE_CLIENT2, but I don't know how to make Spring Security to check request domain against these authorities.

Is there some out of the box support, or should I get my hands dirty and intercept authentication process with some custom code checking request domain and user's authorities?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a custom AuthenticationProvider as well as a custom UserNamePasswordAuthenticationToken in order to define more authentication attributas than login/password.

This way you can add domain as a third authetication attribute and use it as you want in authenticate method of your custom AuthenticationProvider. Inside this method you will have to cast the authenticationToken.

You will also need a custom UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter that creates the instance of your custom UserNamePasswordAuthenticationToken and puts the domain value that you can obtain from HttpRequest (if this attribute is provided by the user as a third field of login form) or ServletContext (if you want to take dns domain name).

Of course, your database and user model object needs to have enough info about domain and ROLES to init credentials authorities.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I was looking exactly for like this - way to start, I think I'll be able to handle it from here, thanks!