# Domain (host) dependant content in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security

We are developping an application using Spring MVC 4.X. The goal is, that it should be accessible to different clients on different domains (probably just subdomains in production). Like client1 will access it on `client1.ourapp.com`, Client 2 will use `client2.our.app.com`, etc.

Since the app is same for all clients, only content differs, we'd like to run in on just one Tomcat server.

My question is: How to best handle this using SpringMVC? I already solved login using separated accounts for each client (and admin accounts that can log anywhere) using Spring Security using answer to my previous question: [Authentication based on http domain with spring-security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32267675/authentication-based-on-http-domain-with-spring-security/32268502#32268502) To make it fully work, I extended `HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository` so it creates separate `SpringSecurityContextKey` for every requested domain.

I'm thinking about using this Security Context for storing information about current client into that, so I could get from SecurityContextHolder, but I don't feel its very clean.

Quick solution would be checking incoming request's `serverName` and find `Client` instance in database, but I don't like this either. Since client won't change during user's session, I think it is ineffective to query object from database during every request.

Should I declare my own filter and handle the decision and caching using that? What other options do I have, is there some recommended one?

In any case, I'd like to be able to ask something like `getCurrentClient()`  in any controller. Is there better approach than creating abstract controller and keep in mind that every controller has to extend it? Isn't there something like `@ControllerAdvice`, that would "inject" arbitrary method to all controllers?

Comment: When you say `content`, do you mean static content, such as, display labels - stored in `.properties` files?

Comment: No, all the contet is dynamic, loaded form database. Every client can for example choose logo to be dispalyed in the header. Plus also every client has completely separated data. So If our application was a phone book, each client would see and manage only his own contacts

Comment: What you are looking for a multi-tenancy solution at the data access level.  You should research multi-tenancy support in your data access layer (for example, Hibernate has multi-tenant support).  Spring MVC does not provide any out-of-the-box support for what you are looking for because you are not looking at a presentation-specific problem but a data-access problem.

Comment: I didn't knopw about multi-tenancy support in Hibernate, we're using Hibernate so this looks nice. But still still to root of my problem, where to store tenant identifier? Probably just put it to session first request and let CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver read it from there?

Comment: Also it raises some question about possibility of sharing some tables across tenants (which we may or may not need). Also we will have one "master" application where, admin can see (some of the) data of all clients. I am little bit affraid of cross schema SELECTs, but I can do my research on this

Comment: Use a servlet filter to determine the client ID from the domain name, put that ID on a `ThreadLocal` and then retrieve it from the `ThreadLocal` in an `AbstractRoutingDataSource`.  Hibernate provides support for multiple types of tenancy models so you have lots of flexibility there.

Answer (score 0):

First, I'd recommend using a database server that supports multiple databases per cluster (anything other than MySQL really), and store each tenant in their own database, for security.

Extend [AbstractRoutingDataSource](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/lookup/AbstractRoutingDataSource.html) to choose your DataSource at run-time. See https://spring.io/blog/2007/01/23/dynamic-datasource-routing/ .

You could also use [ResourceBundleThemeSource](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/ui/context/support/ResourceBundleThemeSource.html) and make a "theme" for each tenant. Create your own HostnameThemeResolver similar to [CookieThemeResolver](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/theme/CookieThemeResolver.html).

You could also make a hostname-based ResourceBundleViewResolver that loads different views based on the hostname. This would require a little bit of custom coding though.

Comment: Interesting, I'll study it, thanks! But there is one more thing I forgot to mention, we'll also have "master" application collecting data from all the clients and I'm little bit afraid of performance while doing cross database selects and combining result into one view.. I should benchmark this.